# Decrypt encrypted string using PKCS1-OAEP in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, node-crypto, pkcs#1

I am getting an information which is encrypted using PKCS1-OAEP algorithm in python and I want to decrypt the information in node.js.

I found the crypto library of node.js. Looks like there are two functions to decrypt this info: a) createCipherIV and b) PrivateDecrypt. I can't use privateDecrypt since node is referring to a previous version of crypto which didn't have this function and upgrading the crypto library version is something I can't do at this point because of time constraints, b) I can't use createCipherIV since it doesn't have support for pkcs1-oaep. So, I am almost blocked here. Can you help me in figuring out the correct library/function to decrypt the information? 
https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipheriv_algorithm_key_iv_options link says that PKCS1-OAEP is not supported by CreateCipherIV but I read somewhere that OpenSSL does support OAEP, couldn't find any proper documentation for that though.

Answer (score 0):

you could refer to ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-1/pkcs-1v2-1.pdf and remove OAEP yourself ... OAEP removal starts on page 20